# No puedo ocultar una columna de un JTable en JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Estoy intentando ocultar una columna en un JTable, y puedo ocultar todas, menos esa específicamente. Utilizo estas lineas de código para ocultar las columnas.

```
tableEventos.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(0);
    tableEventos.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(0);
    tableEventos.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(0);
```

Adjunto también como se ve la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deseas ocultar la columna "Titulo" o "Fecha" ?

Comment: Quiero ocultar la que tiene los puntos suspensivos

Comment: Usa el método `removeColumn()`, especificando los indices de las columnas que deseas eliminar, en este caso sería de la columna con indice 2 en adelante... agregué respuesta.

Comment: Si utilizo ese metodo no puedo traer la informacion de esa columna. Mi pregunta es porque si puedo ocultar las otras,pero esa no.

Comment: Te refieres a la columna con los puntos?

Comment: si señor la columna con puntos

Comment: se les olvido hacerte la pregunta clave... ¿Para qué querrías eliminar una columna?

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes usar el método `removeColumn()`** mediante el cual puedes eliminar cualquier columna especificada en `JTable`.

Ejemplo:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = tableEventos.getTableHeader().getColumnModel();

//Remueve tercer columna
tcm.removeColumn(tcm.getColumn(2));
//Remueve cuarta columna
tcm.removeColumn(tcm.getColumn(3));
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si habrás resuelto ya tu problema, en cualquier caso, además del código que has puesto con getTableHeader, debes hacer lo mismo con getColumnModel() como te pongo debajo.

`tablaEventos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(0); tablaEventos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(0); tablaEventos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(0);`